# Disable button if the selected row contains a specific value ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm trying to disable a remove button for my grid if the row contains a specific value.

I've already have a condition in my ng-disable for the button (and want to keep that), but I want to add a second one, ex:

```
mySelection.title == 'important'
```

How till this behave if I select two rows? It won't iterate through the selected rows and check if the rows contains a title with important, so how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `function()` in `ng-disabled`

for EX:

```
<button ng-disabled="isDisabled(mySelection.title, parameter2)"> Remove </button>
```

in controller,

```
 $scope.isDisabled = function(parameter1, parameter2) {
     // do your comparisons and return true or false 

     // for ex:

     // if(parameter1 == 'important' && parameter2 == 'spmeOtherValue') {
     //     return true;
     // } else {
     //     return false;
     // }
 }
```

Comment: the return false doesn't affect the disabled attribute, the button still appears even if the if condition sets it to false.